# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) I tri Flask

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/review/<isbn>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def review(isbn):
    uid = session["user"].id
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = db.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn=:isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchall()
        rating = db.execute("SELECT * FROM review join book ON review.bid = book.id join users On review.uid = users.id WHERE isbn =:isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchall()
        res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?", params={"key": "LZdw0fSUvZVtB5Gprc6DQ", "isbns": isbn})
        bookinfo = res.json()
        avr = bookinfo['books'][0]['average_rating']
        rvr = bookinfo['books'][0]['work_ratings_count']
        print(isbn)
        return render_template("review.html",
                               data=data, rating=rating, avr=avr, rvr=rvr)
```

**Error:**

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) I tri
```

Comment: Hi....WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you for comment but this crazy i could not find any option to edit it back

Answer (score 0):

The response from the `https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?key=LZdw0fSUvZVtB5Gprc6DQ&isbns=test` is not json I am not sure of the isbns value that needs to be passed so tried with test.

Response is not in JSON format:

```
No books match those ISBNs.
```

Are you sure the response from the url is in json format for a valid isbns? If yes can you share a test isbns.

Comment: yout can test this book isbn 0553803700

Comment: with this `0553803700` I am able to execute the flask app! It throws the error `review.html` not found - which is valid as I don't have any html file. I think so if the response by the goodreads url is not json you need to handle that!

Comment: ok...let me know in case you have issues..if not then accept the answer!